# How to redefine sequence of integers with an excel function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series of coordinates which increment in steps of 20 as follows:

```
5833137
5833157
5833177
5833197
```

I need to transform this sequence such as that the first integer 5833137 = 1 and the following integer 5833157 is a 2.

so that the results would be as follows:
    1
    2
    3
    4

How could I do this in excel or python?

Comment: Err... $(x-5833117)/20$?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have data in column A and are putting the result in column B.

This is a series with a constant difference $d$.  For initial value of $x_1$ the $n$th term is $x_n = x_1 + d \cdot (n-1).$

You have $x_n$ and are looking to backtrack out $n$.  By inspection we see that $d=20$.

Solving for $n$ gives

$$n = \frac{x_n - x_1}{d} + 1.$$

In Excel this would be

`B1=((A1-5833137)/20)+1`